# Web scraping in R of an attribute containing a substring

Tags: r, xpath, rvest, xml2

I'm using the xml2 package in R to scrape data from a webpage.  The text that I want to scrape is enclosed by the  tags shown below:

```
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl01&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species A    
</a></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl02&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species B   </a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl03&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Sepcies C    </a></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl04&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species D</a></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl05&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species E    </a></td>
```

I tried using the following lines of code in R:

```
library(xml2)
page = read_html(website)
nodes = html_nodes(page, xpath='//td/a[@href*="javascript"]')
```

With the code above, I just want to extract all the  nodes that have an href attribute that contain the substring "javascript", but I get an error message below:

```
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
Warning message:
In xpath_search(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns, num_results = Inf) :
Invalid expression [1207]
```

I'd be grateful if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks for everyone's time.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you tied to using `xpath`? Otherwise, you can do: `jscripts <- page %>% rvest::html_nodes('td') %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes('a') %>% 
  rvest::html_attr('href') %>% 
  .[grepl('javascript', .)]`. You will need to use the `magrittr` package for the pipe operator.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `contains` in your `xpath` to find anchor tags that have `href` containing the text you are interested in:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
website <- '<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl01&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species A    
</a></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl02&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species B   </a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl03&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Sepcies C    </a></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl04&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species D</a></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl05&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species E    </a></td>'
page <- read_html(website)
nodes <- html_nodes(page, xpath='//td/a[contains(@href,"javascript")]')

> nodes
{xml_nodeset (5)}
[1] <a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new &#10;WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterConte ...
[2] <a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new&#10;WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterConten ...
[3] <a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new&#10;WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterConten ...
[4] <a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new&#10;WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterConten ...
[5] <a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new&#10;WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterConten ...
>
```